# How to adjust font size for various devices

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a Delphi app designed for Android devices. Using a font size of 14px, it looks perfect for a 5" device. But when the same app is run on a  PocketBook 7", the font looks very tiny. Although the position and size of the elements are adjusting accordingly to the size, thanks to layout and anchors.

Any idea on how to change the font according to screen size ?

Comment: Use a different view for the larger screen, so you can then specify a larger font. Otherwise, you will have to detect the screen size at runtime and scale the font size accordingly in code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, that's what i did, and how can i make your comment as an answer?

Comment: you can't make my comment into an answer, only I can do that. But you can post your own answer, if you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, i opted for the second solution, i detect the screen size at runtime and scale the font size accordingly in code

Comment: Just curious how you went about scaling the font? With the TextSettings.Font.Size property or the Scale.X and Scale.Y properties?

Comment: I used TextSettings.Font.Size property for the font, and Position.X properties for the position of components